# How to apply no assume unchanged for a directory in git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have ignored a directory using this command :-

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Now I want to remove from ignore list. I can remove a file from ignore list using below command :-

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged fileName
```

My question is how to do it for a directory ?
And where do I find all ignore file list ?

Comment: Why would the same method not work?

Comment: it's not working. That's why I have posted question here.

Comment: I have tried it before commenting, and it works just fine for me. That is, `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')`. How have you determined that it doesn't work for you? FWIW, I have checked that it works with `git diff`, where the modifications I made to files are seen again. And does the output of `git ls-files` look correct when run by itself?

Comment: (By the way, the `| tr '\n' ' '` part is unnecessary but harmless. Newlines are a perfectly valid word splitting character with shells' default settings.)

Comment: git doesn't track directories.  All the methods mentioned work perfectly for files, and files *in* directories.  You cannot apply --assume-unchanges, or even --skip-worktree to a directory.